# Blade foreach loop throws error when empty

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I can't understand why this isn't working.

I have a many-to-many relationship in Laravel between two models for Post and Tag.

When showing the post I have this code in my blade template:

```
@if(!empty($page->tags))
    @foreach($page->tags as $tag)
        @if($loop->last)
            {{$tag->name}}
        @else
            {{$tag->name}},
        @endif
    @foreach
@endif
```

However when there are no tags on a post it throws this error:

> Undefined offset: 1
> Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions::handleError
> vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Compilers/Concerns/CompilesLoops.php:95

If I comment out the foreach loop all is fine. But because of the if statement the foreach loop shouldn't run but apparently tries to. I tried other expressions in my if statement too including

```
@if(count($page->tags) > 0)
```

and

```
@if(null !== $page->tags)
```

nothing seems to work. I am at a loss as how to gracefully handle the absence of tags.

if I dd($page->tags) it shows its just an empty array so I don't understand why this won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not closing your @foreach, you used a second one. But please take into account the information below!

```
@if(!empty($page->tags))
    @foreach($page->tags as $tag)
        @if($loop->last)
            {{$tag->name}}
        @else
            {{$tag->name}},
        @endif
    @endforeach
@endif
```

*** Related and possibly useful for similar errors **

Your issue here is you are getting a Collection using $page->tags, and it does not interact with empty() the way you think it would.

In php:

```
$obj = (object) [];
empty($obj);

// returns false
```

And a laravel Collection is an object, so even if $page->tags, has no items in it, you are essentially doing:

```
empty(collect())
// returns false
```

If you can guarantee the $page->tags is always set then you can use the collection method:

```
@if($page->tags->isNotEmpty())
@endif
```

However if sometimes $page->tags is null (ie. tags is not loaded on page), then you can use:

```
@if(isset($page->tags))
@endif
```

All of that said, IF $page->tags is always present (loaded), then the @foreach syntax should not error, since Collection is iterable, and would be equivalent to doing `foreach ([] as $item) {}`.

Comment: I must be doing something else wrong I just don't know what. Both @if($page->tags->isNotEmpty()) and @if(isset($page->tags)) are not working either, same error.

Comment: @user738974 Can you share the {{ dd($page->tags) }} inside the if, where the issue is being caused?

Comment: @user738974 BAHAHAHA. We both missed it. Updating answer.

Comment: yup, that just happened....and that is how I know it is too late...haha thanks for the help! And just like that it works, without the if statement even....good catch...

Comment: @user738974 np!